# Matrix to quaternion and back does not give same result

Tags: python, quaternions

I'm converting a matrix (M) to a quaternion so that I can e.g. lerp between two different transformation matrices making a smooth animation of an image where I need to make the video frames myself.

When I convert back from the quaternion to a matrix as a test, this new matrix is very far from being the same as the one that became the quat.

```
import numpy as np
from transforms3d import quaternions

M = np.array([[  0.757403109,  -0.186744161,   145.541734],
 [ -0.154492906,   0.626185286,   100.878814],
 [ -0.000294826495,  -0.000344726091,   1.00000000]])


quat = quaternions.mat2quat(M)


testM = quaternions.quat2mat(quat)
print("TEST: M original")
print(M)
print("TEST: quat back to mat (testM)")
print(testM)
print("Why not the same")
print ("quat")
print(quat)
print("quat of testM")
print(quaternions.mat2quat(testM))

#Scaling gives same result, scale M to be -1. to 1
mmax = np.amax(M)
scaleTestM = M / mmax
print("M Scaled")
print(scaleTestM)
quatOfScaled = quaternions.mat2quat(scaleTestM)
print("Quat of scaled")
print(quaternions.quat2mat(quatOfScaled))
```

Do I miss something of what a quaternion actually can represent or is the code wrong?
If this cannot work, other suggestions on how to move smoothly between two transformation matrices is appreciated.

Python 3.6

Console output is this:

> ```
>     TEST: M original
>    [[  7.57403109e-01  -1.86744161e-01   1.45541734e+02]
>     [ -1.54492906e-01   6.26185286e-01   1.00878814e+02]
>      [ -2.94826495e-04  -3.44726091e-04   1.00000000e+00]]
>     TEST: quat back to mat (testM)
>     [[ 0.38627453 -0.42005089  0.8211877 ]
>      [-0.54462197  0.61466344  0.57059247]
>      [-0.74443193 -0.6676422   0.00865989]]
>     Why not the same
>     quat
>     [ 0.70880143 -0.43673539  0.55220671 -0.04393723]
>     quat of testM
>     [ 0.70880143 -0.43673539  0.55220671 -0.04393723]
>     M Scaled
>     [[  5.20402697e-03  -1.28309699e-03   1.00000000e+00]
>      [ -1.06150244e-03   4.30244486e-03   6.93126372e-01]
>      [ -2.02571789e-06  -2.36857210e-06   6.87088145e-03]]
>     Quat of scaled
>     [[ 0.38627453 -0.42005089  0.8211877 ]
>      [-0.54462197  0.61466344  0.57059247]
>      [-0.74443193 -0.6676422   0.00865989]]
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple matrix representations that are true for a given Quaternion. The information about which of these representations you originally used, is lost when you transform your matrix to a Quaternion.

See e.g. matrix-representations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and analyzed it a bit deeper.

The description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion describes 48 possible matrix representations of quaternions. I tried to construct rotation matrices out of those, and store the information which one to be used, but it did not work. The reason is that quaternion matrix representations have nothing todo with a rotation transformation matrix. took me a day to find this out.

The relevant part for this issue is in the chapter

> Three-dimensional and four-dimensional rotation groups

> The set of all unit quaternions (versors) forms a 3-sphere S3 and a
> group (a Lie group) under multiplication, double covering the group
> SO(3,ℝ) of real orthogonal 3×3 matrices of determinant 1 since two
> unit quaternions correspond to every rotation under the above
> correspondence. See the plate trick.

so it is not enough to have a normalized transformation matrix, the determinant has to be 1. Once this condition is satisfied you can create a rotation quaternion and convert it back to the rotation transformation matrix. If the condition is not met the quaternion will be undefined and therefore produce a different matrix when converted back to a matrix.

You can construct such a matrix from yours by using the cross product of two of the vectors from the matrix, and use the cross product of the result.

```
M = np.array([[0.757403109, -0.186744161, 145.541734],
              [-0.154492906, 0.626185286, 100.878814],
              [-0.000294826495, -0.000344726091, 1.00000000]])

quat = quaternions.mat2quat(M)

testM = quaternions.quat2mat(quat)
print("TEST: M original")
det = np.linalg.det(M)
print("M det:"+str(det))
print(M)
print("TEST: quat back to mat (testM)")
print(testM)
print("Why not the same")
print("quat")
print(quat)
print("quat of testM")
print(quaternions.mat2quat(testM))

# Scaling gives same result, scale M to be -1. to 1
mmax = np.amax(M)
scaleTestM = M / mmax
print("M Scaled")
det = np.linalg.det(scaleTestM)
print("M Scaled  det:"+str(det))
print(scaleTestM)
quatOfScaled = quaternions.mat2quat(scaleTestM)
print("Quat of scaled")
print(quaternions.quat2mat(quatOfScaled))

v1 = M[0]
v2 = M[1]
v3 = M[2]

v1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)
v2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
v3 = v3 / np.linalg.norm(v3)

print(v1)
print(v2)
print(v3)

v33 = np.cross(v1, v2)
v33 = v33 / np.linalg.norm(v33)

v22 = np.cross(v1, v33)
v22 = v22 / np.linalg.norm(v22)
scaledOrthoM = np.array([v1, v22, v33])
print("M Scaled")
det = np.linalg.det(scaledOrthoM)
print("M Scaled det:"+str(det))
print(scaledOrthoM)

if det == -1:
    v33 = v33 * -1
    scaledOrthoM = np.array([v1, v22, v33])
    det = np.linalg.det(scaledOrthoM)
    print("M Scaled det:"+str(det))
quatOfScaledOrtho = quaternions.mat2quat(scaledOrthoM)
print("Quat of scaled")
print(quaternions.quat2mat(quatOfScaledOrtho))
```

Console output is this:

```
TEST: M original
M det:0.5119378064538171
[[ 7.57403109e-01 -1.86744161e-01  1.45541734e+02]
 [-1.54492906e-01  6.26185286e-01  1.00878814e+02]
 [-2.94826495e-04 -3.44726091e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
TEST: quat back to mat (testM)
[[ 0.38627453 -0.42005089  0.8211877 ]
 [-0.54462197  0.61466344  0.57059247]
 [-0.74443193 -0.6676422   0.00865989]]
Why not the same
quat
[ 0.70880143 -0.43673539  0.55220671 -0.04393723]
quat of testM
[ 0.70880143 -0.43673539  0.55220671 -0.04393723]
M Scaled
M Scaled  det:1.6605599862106246e-07
[[ 5.20402697e-03 -1.28309699e-03  1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.06150244e-03  4.30244486e-03  6.93126372e-01]
 [-2.02571789e-06 -2.36857210e-06  6.87088145e-03]]
Quat of scaled
[[ 0.38627453 -0.42005089  0.8211877 ]
 [-0.54462197  0.61466344  0.57059247]
 [-0.74443193 -0.6676422   0.00865989]]
[ 0.00520395 -0.00128308  0.99998564]
[-0.00153144  0.00620718  0.99997956]
[-2.94826465e-04 -3.44726056e-04  9.99999897e-01]
M Scaled
M Scaled det:-1.0
[[ 0.00520395 -0.00128308  0.99998564]
 [ 0.66862666 -0.74358506 -0.00443364]
 [-0.74358006 -0.66864013  0.00301168]]
M Scaled det:1.0
Quat of scaled
[[ 0.00520395 -0.00128308  0.99998564]
 [ 0.66862666 -0.74358506 -0.00443364]
 [ 0.74358006  0.66864013 -0.00301168]]
```